# How to fix this error: nullreferenceexception was unhandled

Tags: c#, nullreferenceexception

I have a problem with C# and need help.

I created a text file which included an IP Address and Port pairs; one pair per line. It's structure is like this:

```
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
```

This is the code.

```
public void Filter()
        {
            // Read proxy from text file

            string ppath = @"C:\Program Files\HTE\IP.txt";
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(ppath);

            /* 
            Proxies in the text file have a contruction like this: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
            It includes more than 11k proxies
            Now start to collect ip
            */

            for (int i = 0; i < 11000; i++)
            {
                if (i > 0)
                {
                    // Create a loop to ignore the line(s) which has been filter

                    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
                    {
                        // When j = 0, that mean it has an ignore line

                        sr.ReadLine();
                        GC.Collect();
                    }

                    // Read new line

                    string str_2 = sr.ReadLine();
                    int position_2 = str_2.IndexOf(":");

                    // Get ip

                    string str_ip_2 = str_2.Substring(0, position_2);
                    int tail_2 = str_2.Length - position_2;
                    string str_tmp_2 = str_2.Substring(position_2, tail_2);
                    int subtraction_2 = str_tmp_2.Length - 1;

                    // Get port

                    string str_port_2 = str_tmp_2.Substring(1, subtraction_2);
                    GC.Collect();
                }
                else if (i == 0)
                {
                    string str = sr.ReadLine();

                    // find ":" in the postion of the first line

                    int position = str.IndexOf(":");

                    // Get ip

                    string str_ip = str.Substring(0, position);

                    // The tail of string in line is proxy port

                    int tail = str.Length - position;
                    string str_tmp = str.Substring(position, tail);
                    int subtraction = str_tmp.Length - 1;

                    // Get port

                    string str_port = str_tmp.Substring(1, subtraction);
                    GC.Collect();
                }
            }
```

Error code:

```
string str_2 = sr.ReadLine();
int position_2 = str_2.IndexOf(":");
```

I have tried many ways, but I couldn't fix it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Your call to `sr.ReadLine()` is most likely returning null, making `str_2` null, and causing `str_2.IndexOf` to throw the exception.

You have 2 calls to `.ReadLine()`.  How many lines of data are you actually reading?  If only one line, the 2nd call will return null, causing the above.